# NSJSONSerialization use different serialization name for properties

Tags: ios, serialization, properties, nsjsonserialization

i would like to use the NSJSONSerialization class to parse my json String to a pojo class.

```
@interface ServerData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *changeString;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *localization;
@end
```

Now the problem is, that my json String differs a lot from the names in the class. I want to keep the names for the variables as they are, but want to parse a json attribute called 'XYZ_date' to the variable 'date' in my class.

How can i change the serialization names in my class so NSJSONSerialization parses the e.g. 'XYZ_date' json attribute into the 'date' NSString?

For example in Android i would do:

```
@SerializedName('XYZ_date')
String date;
```

Any help appreciated.
Best regards
John

Answer (score 0):

Okay, NSJSONSerialization is used to get a NSDictionary equivalent of a JSON string. 
You can initialize your object by mapping the data corresponding to different keys.

Pseudocode will look something like the below -

[serverData setDate:[serializedDict objectForKey:@"XYZ_date"]];

But, If you want the boiler plate covered and just want to get going, there are many open sources which a lot of developers have put in..

one such example is https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

Hope this helps